# The second derivative is a symmetric operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the space of the functions two times differentiable in $[0,1]$ that are $0$ in $f(0)$ and $f(1)$. Let $D$ be the derivative operator. Proof that $D^2$ is a symmetric operator.

I already prove that the derivative is a anti-symmetric operator, we do $$\langle Df,g\rangle  = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{df}{dt}g \ dt = [fg]_0^1 - \int_0^1 \frac{dg}{dt} f\ dt=-\langle f,Dg\rangle.$$

thus, we have $D^T=-D.$ My first question is: Can i use this inner product? The question does not give an specific inner product to use.

For the second derivative, we should have $$\int_0^1 \frac{d^2f}{dt^2} g \ dt = \int_0^1f \frac{d^2g}{dt^2}\ dt$$

but I'm struggling to prove this, I've tryed to use two integrations by parts but it didn't help. Any hint?  Thanks!

Comment: That is the correct inner product. Do the same procedure as above, just do one derivative at a time. You might need the assumption that $f'$ and $g'$ are zero at the endpoints as well.

Comment: $\langle D^2f,g\rangle=- \langle Df,Dg\rangle$...

Comment: Cameron, can i assume the derivatives are $0$? This was the step that looks weird to me

Comment: I guess that if you compute following Cameron's suggestion, you do not need to require that the derivatives vanish at 0 and 1, but just that f and g do.

Comment: I computed it and i actually got the answer, when we open the integrals we have the same product of derivatives. Thanks guys! But how can i do it using ur comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}\langle D^2f,g\rangle  &=& \int_{0}^{1}\frac{df}{dt}\left(\frac{df}{dt}\right)g \ dt = \left[\left(\frac{df}{dt}\right)g\right]_0^1 - \int_0^1\frac{df}{dt}\frac{dg}{dt} \ dt\\
&\stackrel{(*)}=&-\int_0^1\frac{df}{dt}\frac{dg}{dt} \ dt\\
&=&\left[f\left(\frac{dg}{dt}\right)\right]_0^1 +
 \int_0^1 f\left(\frac{d^2g}{dt^2}\right) dt\stackrel{(*)}= \langle f, D^2g\rangle\\
\end{eqnarray}
where $(*)$ hold, since $f(0)=f(1)=g(0)=g(1)=0$.